# Realtime Database - How can I use the md5 hashing inside the Rules?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

```
{
  "rules": {    
    "users": {
      "$uid": {        
        "$experiment_id": {
            ".read": "data.child('sharedEmails').child(hashing.md5(auth.email)).val() === true",
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the [Firebase RTDB rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database) and [Firestore rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/index-all) - only Firestore has [`hashing.`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.hashing).